# Subsetting participants based on their frequency of interactions in R

Tags: r, filter, subset, event-log, interaction

I'm relatively new to using R so apologies in advance if my question requires a very obvious answer! My work involves working with event logs and I am currently trying to subset clients based on their number of interactions with the service. Here's an illustrative example:-

```
Client ID               Event
7749-2388              hei856 
4553-9903              jje783 
3423-8850              iew456
3423-8850              msk111
4553-9903              hjl009 
4553-9903              kii906
```

So as you can see, client 4553-9903 had three different interactions with the service, client 3423-8850 had two different interactions with the service and finally client 7749-2388 only had one interaction. My aim is to subset the clients based on the amount of interactions with the service, so those clients with *N* interactions are in one `data.frame` each. My issue is that the `data.frame` I am working with has 150,000 rows of different interactions, which equates to around 50,000 unique clients, so it is not really feasible to manually type in each individual client ID like so:

```
subset(df, Client ID=="4553-9903")
```

Is there a way to subset my data so that all clients who had, for example, 3 interactions with the service are in one `data.frame`, and so on?. I hope my problem isn't too hard to understand and any help I can get would be really appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Creating all these data frames sounds like it will get messy fast. Why not add a column that contains number of interactions (e.g., `df %<>% group_by(Client.ID) %>% mutate(interactions = n()) %>% ungroup`) and then just filter when you want to look at a specific number of interactions (e.g., `df %>% filter(interactions == 3)`)? This way you keep everything in a single data frame.

Comment: Thank you @Lyngbakr!. I think this worked a treat!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend storing the data subsets in a `list` (you will have the full `*apply`/`purrr::*map` family of methods at your disposal to operate on the `list` element).

Here is a `tidyverse` option

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by(Client.ID) %>%
    mutate(n = n()) %>%
    split(., .$n) %>%
    map(~.x[, 1:2])
#$`1`
## A tibble: 1 x 2
## Groups:   Client.ID [1]
#  Client.ID Event
#  <fct>     <fct>
#1 7749-2388 hei856
#
#$`2`
## A tibble: 2 x 2
## Groups:   Client.ID [1]
#  Client.ID Event
#  <fct>     <fct>
#1 3423-8850 iew456
#2 3423-8850 msk111
#
#$`3`
## A tibble: 3 x 2
## Groups:   Client.ID [1]
#  Client.ID Event
#  <fct>     <fct>
#1 4553-9903 jje783
#2 4553-9903 hjl009
#3 4553-9903 kii906
```

Explanation: We group entries by `Client.ID`, count the number of entries per `Client.ID` and split the data into subsets based on that count. The names of the `list` entries correspond to the multiplicity of the `Client.ID`s.

Perhaps alternatively I might make sense to split data by `Client.ID` instead of by `Client.ID` multiplicity, and then operate on the corresponding the `list`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "'Client ID'               Event
 7749-2388              hei856
 4553-9903              jje783
 3423-8850              iew456
 3423-8850              msk111
 4553-9903              hjl009
 4553-9903              kii906", header = T)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This actually worked quite well also!!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be

```
df2<- read.csv("stack_frequency_multi_df.csv",stringsAsFactors = F) #your data
str(df2)
df2$frequency<- as.numeric(ave(df2$client_id,df2$client_id,FUN = length)) ##this will create frequency based on client id 

out <- split( df2 , f = df2$frequency) ##based on the frequency of the client id it will create multiple lists.
list2env(out,envir=.GlobalEnv) ##this will create data frame from all the lists created above 
#below function will save every list as a CSV file which will make your work easier 
Map(write.csv,out,filenames,row.names = F)
```

I hope It helps